# Modifying U=mxn SVD Algorithm to U=mxm Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, svd

I have painstakingly ported this Python source "[svd.py](http://stitchpanorama.sourceforge.net/Python/svd.py)" to C++.  I confirm it works for the example it comes with.  While testing another example ([this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Example), from Wikipedia), the assert statement trips because $m < n$.

I find this somewhat of a curious constraint.  It seems to fail mainly because the matrix $U$ (named $u$ in the source) is initialized as an $m \times n$ matrix (as opposed to the $m \times m$ matrix it is in the definition of a SVD).  It's pretty simple to initialize $U$ instead to an $m \times m$ matrix (and, say, pad with zeroes), but this causes some of the code to break for some other examples.

Why would $U$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, and how can I fix the algorithm to work on all sizes of matrices?

EDIT: If the SVD is $M=U_1\Sigma_1 V_1^*$, I came up with the idea of computing the SVD of $M^*$ to get $M^*=V_1\Sigma_1^*U_1^*=U_2\Sigma_2 V_2^*$.  From here, I use that substitution to get the desired $U_1$, $\Sigma_1$, $V_1$ out.  This produces a result that multiplies back through correctly, but is it a proper SVD?

Comment: Why are you porting that particular svd algorithm when there are tons of well-implemented svd's in C++ already?

Comment: @Batman it needs to integrate with some existing C++ sources in a very particular way, and external libraries aren't an option.  I wasn't able to find a compact enough SVD algorithm to adapt to my system.

Comment: @IanMallett Since there are plenty of implementations, you can either use a library (I don't see why you can't, but I don't know your constraints), either extract the important source code and integrate it in your system. There are good implementations in C (for example from gsl), Fortran (for example from Lapack), and probably C++ as well. So I don't really see the problem. Usually, the simple way to go is just to find a Lapack compiled for your OS/compiler, and integrate it, within any language (even Excel's VBA).

Comment: Ad EDIT: Yes, it is a correct "economy" SVD of a "wide" matrix. It depends on the application whether or not you need a "full" SVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sounds like the routine is built for overdetermined systems. The standard theoretical trick is to work with $\mathbf{A}^{*}$ in lieu of $\mathbf{A}$. An underdetermined system is going to contend with infinite solution space.
2. Given a matrix of rank $\rho$,
   $$
    \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho},
   $$
   the singular value decomposition is
   $$
   \begin{align}
     \mathbf{A} &=
     \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
   %
    &=
   % U 
     \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
        \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
     \end{array} \right]  
   % Sigma
     \left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
        \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
        0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
        \vdots && \ddots \\
          & & & \sigma_{k} \\
          & & & & 0 & \\
        \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
        0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
     \end{array} \right]
   % V 
     \left[ \begin{array}{c}
        \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
        \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
     \end{array} \right]  \\
   %
     & =
   % U
      \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
       \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{k}} & \color{red}{u_{k+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{n}}
     \end{array} \right]
   % Sigma
     \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
        \mathbf{S}_{k\times k} & \mathbf{0} \\
        \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
     \end{array} \right]
   % V
      \left[ \begin{array}{c}
       \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
       \vdots \\
       \color{blue}{v_{k}^{*}} \\
       \color{red}{v_{k+1}^{*}} \\
       \vdots \\ 
       \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
     \end{array} \right]
   %
   \end{align}
   $$
   Your problem may correspond to $\rho = n$.
3. The least squares solution highlights the uniqueness issue. Given the solution vector $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$, and the data vectors $b \in \mathbb{C}^{m}$, and the restriction that $b\notin \color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}\right)}$, the least squares solution to $\mathbf{A}x = b$ is
   $$
   x_{LS} = \color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b} + 
    \color{red}{\left( \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A} \right) y}, \quad y\in\mathbb{C}^{n}
   $$
   If the nullspace $\color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\right)}$ is trivial, then $\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A} =\mathbf{I}_n$ and the solution is unique.
4. So yes, we can build the Hermitian conjugate with SVD components. Using the thin form
   $$
     \mathbf{A} = 
   \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}  \mathbf{S} \, \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} 
   %
   \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
   %
   \mathbf{A}^{*} = 
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*}  \mathbf{S} \, \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}
   $$